# NPM - unable to resolve dependency tree

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, bundler, webpack-5

I am having an issue that I cannot seem to resolve.

I was trying to update webpack and webpack-cli in a project and I keep getting errors like the following:

```
npm install webpack@latest  --save-dev  
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: mmsccmsearch@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: webpack-cli@5.1.4
npm ERR! node_modules/webpack-cli
npm ERR!   dev webpack-cli@"^5.1.4" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer webpack-cli@"4.x.x" from @webpack-cli/init@1.1.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@webpack-cli/init
npm ERR!   dev @webpack-cli/init@"^1.1.3" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\blah.blah\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-09-        25T23_54_32_583Z-eresolve-report.txt
```

I have done the following:

1. `rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json`
2. `npm cache clear --force`

I try to install webpack again using the following:
`npm install webpack@latest --save-dev`

I get the same errors.

I checked the versions of node and npm and saw they were out of date.  I updated them so that node is v18.18.0 and npm is 10.1.0

I can get it to work if I add the flag `--legacy-peer-deps` to every command.  However, I shouldn't have to do this.

Is there something wrong with webpack?  Is there something I'm doing wrong or corrupted/misconfigured on my system?

Comment: It's "literally" written what's wrong. You have `webpack-cli` and `@webpack-cli/init` *devDependencies*. `webpack-cli` v5 .1.4 has been installed while `@webpack-cli/init` v1.1.3 requires `webpack-cli` to have **v4.x.x**. So the solution is to use whatever is suggested (using `--legacy-peer-deps` flag) or install a compatible version of a package (`npm i -D webpack-cli@~4`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In attempting to fix an earlier problem, it appears I introduced a different one by adding the `@webpack-cli/init` package manually.

As noted by an individual, who was less than polite, I introduced a conflict in versions which resulted in the errors I received.

As I noted in my post, `--legacy-peer-deps` ensured that I could successfully install/uninstall packages. However, I successfully resolved the issue by uninstalling `@webpack-cli/init` from my project.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following command,

```
npm audit --fix
```